# Overloaded constructor of template member not called

Tags: c++, c++11

Ok, this one drives me mad. I can't figure out why a constructor is not called.

Here is the code:

```
template<class T>
struct JV {
  JV() {}
  JV(const T& t0) : F{{t0}} {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
  std::array<T,1> F;
};


template<class T>
struct RS : public JV<T>
{
  RS(): JV<T>() {}

  RS(const T& rhs) : JV<T>(rhs) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};



template<class T>
struct PS : public JV<T>
{
  PS(): JV<T>() {}

  PS(const T& rhs) : JV<T>(rhs) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};


template<class T>
struct WJ
{
  WJ() {
    std::cout << "WJ::WJ()\n";
  }
};


int main() {
  PS<RS<WJ<float> > > wj;
  std::cout << "go for it\n";
  PS<PS<RS<WJ<float> > > > copy(wj);
}
```

If compiled with GCC g++ 4.7.2 `-std=c++0x` and run the output is:

```
WJ::WJ()
go for it
JV<T>::JV(const T&) [with T = PS<RS<WJ<float> > >]
PS<T>::PS(const T1&) [with T1 = PS<RS<WJ<float> > >; T = PS<RS<WJ<float> > >]
```

Why does `JV<T>::JV(const T&) [with T = PS<RS<WJ<float> > >]` not call the 
overloaded constructor of `PS<RS<WJ<float> > >::PS<RS<WJ<float> > >(const RS<WJ<float> >&)`?

Edit:

Also, it doesn't call it when restricting the overloaded constructor, see above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Templated constructors are never copy constructors.</strike> The compiler is using the copy constructor to construct `PS<RS<WJ<float>>>` inside the `std::array` in `JV`. You are not tracking in your code copy construcotrs so no other message is shown after `JV<T>::JV(T const&)`.

Comment: But it shouldn't use it. It is supposed to construct `PS<RS<WJ<float> > >` from `RS<WJ<float> >`. Why should it call the copy c-tor?

Comment: @Frank: If you instrument `PS` copy constructor you will see that it is called from `JV`'s constructor. Basically the `T` inside the `std::array<T>` is copy constructed from the argument to `JV(T const&)` in the initializer list `JV(T const& rhs) : F{{rhs}} {}`

Comment: What do you mean by *"Templated constructors are never copy constructors"*?  And what does that have to do with this question?  I don't see any templated constructors.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - The constructors for a class template are templated constructors. It's close to a tautology. As for "*Templated constructors are never copy constructors*", it's right there in the standard, sect 12.8 para 2: *A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor ...*

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: There used to be templated constructors in a previous version of the code. My interpretation at the time is that the user was expecting those constructors to be called for the `RS` and `WJ` copies, which I have to admit was a bit of crystal-ball mind-reading of the OP intentions.

Comment: @DavidHammen: If you call constructors for class templates "templated constructors", what do you call the constructor for this class? http://ideone.com/rLqjF

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Oh, okay.  I didn't see the previous version.  But still, I'm not sure what you meant by the statement because: http://ideone.com/8CJw2

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Interesting, because the standard is quite clear in 12.8/2 *A **non-template** constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&,
volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters
have default arguments*. I am unsure as to whether that behavior on that compiler is correct or not. It seems to allow the implicitly declared copy constructor with signature `const Foo&` and the templated constructor with signature `Foo&`...

Comment: ... the behavior is also a bit quirky, it will use that constructor for non-const lvalues if called either in *direct-initialization* or *copy-initialization* manually, but won't be called when an object is returned from a function, for example.